# How solr will delete the documents

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

Am using solr to indexing around 70K documents , i haven't send any deletion policy , but even then the solr deletes few of the documents before completing the complete index of 70K documents, So wanted to understand how is this possible , on what basis solr decides to delete the documents before the complete indexing is done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deletes are probably duplicate ids, meaning that you're seeing an update of a document that was indexed earlier. An update is a delete + an add, so you'll end up with one deleted document counted in the index.

There is no 'deletion policy' that you set in Solr yourself, but depending on how you're feeding Solr content, the framework usually have some way of detecting deleted entries and removing them from Solr as well (in DIH this is `deletedPkQuery`).

Comment: When you say update of earlier indexed document, how solr will identify , will it use unique field which we have specified in the schema.xml or is it something to do with the solr internal will take care of it automatically.

Comment: If two documents with the same uniqueKey is added, the latter replaces the first (automagically - there's nothing you have to do).

Comment: so this uniqueKey were talking about is the one which is specified in the schema file? correct me if am wrong.